# Attach multiple files to an email from Google Docs

Tags: gmail, google-drive

I want to email two files as attachments to a single email in Gmail without downloading them from Google Docs. When viewing all items in Docs, the "Email as attachment" item is disabled in the Share dropdown menu.

First off...why? Second, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58225

"Keep in mind that it's not possible to email multiple docs as attachments."

Looks like your only option is to download multiple docs (More Actions > Export > Download) and attach the resulting zip to an email ... or to go through the "Email as attachment" process multiple times.

Comment: As much as I hate the message, that's a pretty authoritative answer, so I can't shoot the messenger.

Comment: I bet it's a problem they'll eventually solve.

Comment: Man that sucks! I was looking for that exact issue, and this problem is still present a year later :-( A useful answer though.

Comment: When, so much is being made possible with browsers, why not this?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has announced a new feature that lets you [insert files from Drive directly into an email without leaving your Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.in/2012/11/gmail-and-drive-new-way-to-send-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is once you have the document open, click on file and then download as a PDF and save to your computer. Then go to your email and upload the files from your computer, and attach as many documents as you need.

Answer (score -1):

Best way would be to upload them to a Dropbox Public folder, get the URL for the files and create a link in Gmail with that URL. This way, when the user clicks the link in their email, it actually downloads the files from the Dropbox server.