# Sending a new mail with another email as an attachment in Gmail

Tags: gmail, attachment

How do I attach an email from a previous conversation or mail to a new message in Gmail?

Forwarding isn't feasible as I need to attach more than one email in a new message to my client.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just forward the previous email?

Comment: I need to attach more than one email for mail communication to my clients. So the way of forwarding emails is not feasible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Gmail, how can I attach an attachment from one email to another, without saving the attachment first or forwarding the message?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/in-gmail-how-can-i-attach-an-attachment-from-one-email-to-another-without-savi)

Answer (score 26):

This should help.

[Google support forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=4c5926d9e0dab6e6&hl=en)

User claudio_maestro answered:

> The correct way to attach an unrelated message is to open it, then open the menu on the right and select "Show Original". It will open a new window with the message in plain text. In your browser, select "Save As" and use the .eml extension. It will create a message that all mail clients (Outlook, Live Mail, Thunderbird...) can open, and it will include all original headers. Then upload that .eml file as an attachment to the message you're sending.

Comment: Awesome.. if you actually need  it..

Comment: LOL. Seems impossible to me to make it even more complicated.

Comment: And opening that *.eml attachment in gmail shows.... plaintext.  This doesn't work, not generally anyway.

Comment: It works if people have a local email client such as Outlook or Thunderbird installed.

Comment: "all mail clients (Outlook, Live Mail, Thunderbird...) can open" - with the exception of gmail itself, of course... :-(

Comment: Easier to just set up Thunderbird with GMail since it can actually forward as attachment natively… But that’s outside the realm of webapps then…